# Unable to Swipe Fotorama Gallery Images on Mobile in Magento PDP Page

Tags: magento2

The problem is that I cannot swipe through the gallery images using my fingers on mobile devices.

I have inspected the JavaScript console, and there are no apparent errors.

I'm seeking help to enable the swipe functionality for the Fotorama gallery on mobile devices. If you've encountered this issue before or have insights into how to make the gallery swipeable on touch devices, I would greatly appreciate your guidance. Any specific code examples or configuration adjustments to address this problem would be valuable.

Thank you for your assistance!

[Click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3UoG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Its a known issue on Version 2.4.6, you can install this patch which should fix the issue.
https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/magento/magento2/pull/37355.diff
https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/37355